# How to create private-public-address keypair with json-rpc client and PHP

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Everyone. 
I am trying to create private-public-address keypair with json-RPC client. 
It's for new coins, not bitcoin or other famous coins. 
So I thought I need to use JSON-RPC client to connect the server(I open the vps and installed the RPC server).

But I can't find any function to create the key pair. I can see the only getnewaddress function. 
But It's only returned the new address.

Please give me answer if you know about that field. 
Thanks.
Goekhan

Answer (score -1):

curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"makekeypair","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://user:pass@0.0.0.0:5788

this will generate the new key pair but i am not sure about the parameters and how to use this key to associate with the wallet address.